# No USB boot option when I tried to install ubuntu from win10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

At first I failed to install Ubuntu 18(deprecated, couldn't boot) because I forgot to enable UEFI, so I switched back to win10, change the disk to GPT and enable UEFI, and delete the ubuntu partition in disk management(i.e., now it is unallocated again).

However, now I couldn't see any USB boot option after I press F12 during startup, and there is a ubuntu option which leads me to win10(why? I have deleted that partition). I don't understand what's going on, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: This is because you must have deleted the Ubuntu partition but not GRUB, I guess.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes I deleted the whole ubuntu partition, but where is the USB boot option?

Comment: @Kulfy You are right, it's grub issue, thanks!

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post the solution in answer section. It might help someone in need. Also, questions without answers looks odd. ;-)